# AWS Elastic Block Storage (EBS) Snapshot Access History

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, snapshot

How can we know who has accessed AWS EBS snapshot which was publicly available? 
I am not able to find the option in AWS management console

Answer (score 0):

**AWS CloudTrail** would contain information about how Amazon EBS snapshots are used *whithin* your own AWS Account.

It is **not possible** to obtain information about how public/shared Amazon EBS snapshots have been used outside of your AWS Account.